Ag-grid: Repeat same row several times based on grouping by array
Here is my data example in csv (real life usage, the data comes pre-formatted in JSON with an array for groups)
name,groups
John,group1|group2
Roger,group1
Melanie,group2|group3

I would like to show in ag-grid a table of users grouped by groups where the same record would show several times
group1
    John
    Roger
group2
    John
    Melanie
group3
    Melanie

I tried exploring the keyCreator (doc here) but to no avail.
Is what I want to do achievable in pure ag-grid fashion ?
I would very much like to avoid having to send several times the same row as I would like to send the dataset only once and not have to re-send if the user changes the grouping (from no grouping to groups for example).
